# Select certain rows by index of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I would select only rows that contain index value into df1.index.

for Example:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   A  B  C  D
1  1  4  9  1
2  4  5  0  2
3  5  5  1  0
22 1  3  9  6
```

and these indexes

```
In[96]:df1.index
Out[96]:
Int64Index([  1,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,  22,  28,  29,  32,], dtype='int64', length=253)
```

I would like this output:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   A  B  C  D
1  1  4  9  1
3  5  5  1  0
22 1  3  9  6
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df[df.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

Or get all intersectioned indices and select by `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index & df1.index]
df = df.loc[np.intersect1d(df.index, df1.index)]
df = df.loc[df.index.intersection(df1.index)]
```

---

```
print (df)
    A  B  C  D
1   1  4  9  1
3   5  5  1  0
22  1  3  9  6
```

EDIT:

> I tried solution: df = df.loc[df1.index]. Do you think that this solution is correct?

Solution is incorrect:

```
df = df.loc[df1.index]
print (df)

      A    B    C    D
1   1.0  4.0  9.0  1.0
3   5.0  5.0  1.0  0.0
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
22  1.0  3.0  9.0  6.0
28  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
C:/Dropbox/work-joy/so/_t/t.py:23: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
  print (df)
```

Comment: I tried solution: ```df = df.loc[df1.index]```. Do you think that this solution is correct?

Comment: @giupardeb - I test it and add to answer. Please check it.

Comment: I want to add that `df = df.loc[df1.index]` doesn't work

Comment: @song0089 - Ya, so use `df = df[df.index.isin(df1.index)]`

Comment: Beware of this usage of `isin()` as it will **not** result in `df` and `df1` always being in the same order.

Answer (score 11):

Passing the index to the row indexer/slicer of .loc now works, you just need to make sure to specify the columns as well, i.e.:

```
df = df.loc[df1.index, :]  # works
```

and NOT

```
df = df.loc[df1.index] # won't work
```

IMO This is more neater/consistent with the expected usage of .loc

Comment: You're right, it seems that the devs have changed the implementation.
However now both seem to raise the KeyError warning if you pass in a list of values that doesn't exist

Comment: This solution has the advantage of ensuring order of df and df1 are the same.

Comment: this only works if `df1`'s entire index is contained in `df`'s index; the accepted answer does not have that limitation